# how to use a while loop in my python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Q) Write a function named collatz() that has one parameter named number. If a number is even, then collatz() should print number // 2 and return this value. If a number is odd, then collatz() should print and return 3 * number + 1. Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps calling
collatz() on that number until the function returns the value 1.

This is the code I wrote for the above problem but I need a small help on how to use the while loop so when I get a ValueError rather than breaking out of the program I want the program to re-execute the program rather than just displaying the print statement in except.

```
try:
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        print(3 * number + 1)
        return 3 * number + 1
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
while x != 1:
    x = collatz(x)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the code from the **[HandlingExceptions - Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)**:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        print(3 * number + 1)
        return 3 * number + 1

has_input_int_number = False 
while has_input_int_number == False: 
    try: # try to convert user input into a int number 
        x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        has_input_int_number = True # will only reach this line if the user inputted a int
        while x != 1:
            x = collatz(x)
    except ValueError: # if it gives a ValueError
        print("Error: Please enter a numerical int value.")
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter a number:  a
Error: Please enter a numerical int value.
Enter a number:  1.5
Error: Please enter a numerical int value.
Enter a number:  5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        print(3 * number + 1)
        return 3 * number + 1
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
while x != 1:
    try:
        x = collatz(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a numerical value")
```

Comment: I wanna know how to use the while loop so when I get a ValueError rather than going to except condition and printing just "Please enter a numerical value" I want the program to re-execute or restart the entire program rather than just displaying that print statement.

Comment: just run the code above, your will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `while True` and `break` if not statified.

```
def collatz(x):
    x= x//2 if x%2==0 else x*3+1
    print(x)
    return x

def func(x):
    while True:
        x = collatz(x)
        if x==1:
            break

def run():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input("Input a positive number: "))
            assert x>0
            func(x)
            break
        except Exception as exc:
            #print("Exception: {}".format(exc))                          
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

[image]